# Recursive including template files fails compilation

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I am trying to use a simple template class to decode different types. I am getting this error

```
Decoder.h:16: error: non-const lvalue reference to type 'CheckDecoder::NormalType' cannot bind to a value of unrelated type 'CheckDecoder::NestedType'
        CheckDecoder::decode(m_value, istr);
                             ^~~~~~~
```

Actually its a part of big project but I am sharing a simple project to show this specific problem. Please help to resolve this issue, also provide some reference to read more about this template issue.

These are the four files in the project

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <NormalType.h>
#include <NestedType.h>
#include <Decoder.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace CheckDecoder;
int main()
{
    Decoder<NormalType> d_normal;
    d_normal.decode(std::cin);

    Decoder<NestedType> d_nested;
    d_nested.decode(std::cin);
    return 0;
}
```

Decoder.h

```
#ifndef DECODER_H
#define DECODER_H

#include <iostream>

namespace CheckDecoder {


template<typename T>
class Decoder
{
public:
    void decode(std::istream& istr)
    {
        // some complex code
        CheckDecoder::decode(m_value, istr);
    }

    T m_value;
};

}
#endif // DECODER_H
```

NormalType.h

```
#ifndef NORMALTYPE_H
#define NORMALTYPE_H

#include <iostream>

namespace CheckDecoder {

class NormalType
{

};

void decode(NormalType& t, std::istream& istr)
{
    // do something
}
}
#endif // NORMALTYPE_H
```

NestedType.h

```
#ifndef NESTEDTYPE_H
#define NESTEDTYPE_H

#include <Decoder.h>

namespace CheckDecoder {

class NestedType
{

private:
    Decoder<int> m_value;
};

void decode(NestedType& t, std::istream& istr)
{
    // do something
}
}

#endif // NESTEDTYPE_H
```

Comment: Why does `Decoder.h` include `NestedType.h`?

Comment: @idclev463035818 If i don't include NestedType.h in Decoder I get error Decoder.h:18: error: no member named 'decode' in namespace 'CheckDecoder'; did you mean simply 'decode'?
        CheckDecoder::decode(m_value, istr);
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        decode

Comment: you have a mutual dependency (or maybe not), Decoder.h and NestedType.h both include each other. Please provide a [mcve]. It is not apparent from the posted code why `Decoder` needs to know about `NestedType`

Comment: @idclev463035818 I have removed the NestedType and Normal Type from Decoder and changed the header file order in main.cpp, now it fails with a different error. I have updated it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way your includes are ordered, in `main.cpp` first `CheckDecoder::decode(NormalType)` is declared, then `CheckDecoder::decode` is used by `Decoder`, and finally `CheckDecoder::decode(NestedType)` is declared. At the point of definition in `Decoder`, only the first declaration is visible; the second doesn't participate in overload resolution. It could have been found by argument-dependent lookup, but the way you call it - with a qualified name - suppresses that.

One possible workaround is to move the call to a scope where other things named `decode` don't get in the way, and then use an unqualified name to allow argument-dependent lookup to do its thing. Something like this:

```
struct DecoderHelper {
  template <typename T>
  static void DoDecode(T& value, std::istream& istr) {
    decode(value, istr);
  }
};

template<typename T>
class Decoder
{
public:
    void decode(std::istream& istr)
    {
        // some complex code
        DecoderHelper::DoDecode<T>(m_value, istr);
    }

    T m_value;
};
```